# Elasticsearch search service with Angular 4

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, elasticsearch-5

I'm having a tough time figuring out how to use Elasticsearch (5.x) with Angular 4.

I installed the ES JS client vie npm and also installed the type definitions via npm install --save @types/elasticsearch.

I'm trying to use [NgbBootstrap Typeahead](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples) for autocomplete. However I keep getting this error `ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'`

So I've been playing around with the formatMatches function to format the input/output because my service returns an `{}` instead of an `[]`. Nothing seems to work.

```
formatMatches = (query: any) => query.hits.**hits**._source.suggestions || '';
```

The second hits, is an array that contains {"_source": {"suggestions": "suggestion_text"}

So now I'm thinking that maybe my service is not quite right because I'm basically using the same HTML that NgbBootstrap gives.

Here is my service

```
    @Injectable()
export class Elasticsearch {
  private results: Observable<Suggestion[]>;

  //private clientElasticsearch: Client;
  private esClient: Client;
  constructor() {
    //this.clientElasticsearch = new Client({
    this.esClient = new Client({
        host: 'http://localhost:9200',
        apiVersion: '5.x',
        log: 'trace'
      });
  }

  //public test_search(value): Observable<SearchResponse<{}>> {
  public search(query): Observable<SearchResponse<{}>> {
    return Observable.fromPromise(<Promise<SearchResponse<{}>>>

      this.esClient.search({
      index: 'query-index',
      body: {
        "query": {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "suggestions": {
              "query": query,
              "max_expansions": 10
              //"lenient": true
            }
          }
        },
        "size": 5,
        "from": 0,
        "_source": ["suggestions"]
      }
    }));
  }
}
```

I'm starting to think that I don't exactly have to use the ES JS client via npm because I know the js client is built to work with promises. Can I simply use a web api like [this](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/12/03/restful-webservice-for-angular2-using-observable/)?

Comment: Was there ever a solution for this?

Comment: Did you figured it out, can you share any idea if you are? @user3125823

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
@Injectable()
export class QueryService {
private _esClient: Client;
private _wildCard = '*';
constructor() {
    this._esClient = new Client({

    host: 'http://localhost:9200',
    log: 'error',

    });
}
getQueryfieldclin(fieldName: string): Observable<Object[]> {
    return Observable.fromPromise(
            <Promise<any>> this._esClient.search({
                'index': 'ft-query',
                'type': 'telco',
                'size': 50,
                'body': {
                    'query': {
                        'bool': {
                            'must': [
                                {
                                    'range': {
                                        'InvoiceDate': {
                                            'gte': '2004-01-01',
                                            'lte': '2017-12-31'
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            'should': [
                                {
                                    'wildcard' : { 'CLIN.keyword'  :  '*'}
                                }
                            ], 'minimum_number_should_match': 1
                        }
                    }
                },
            }),
        )
        .map((response: SearchResponse<string>) => response.hits.hits)
        .do(data => data);
}
```

}